# How To Update Card View layout When Click on it?

Tags: android

I have  added 5 cards on my recycler view. i want to change the whole view of card view while click on it. But only last card is  changing its view while clicking any 5 of them.

i want to replace cardlist layout to replacecard layout while click on card view
 where i am going wrong if anyone help
 ///here is my adapter::

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,  int position)
    {
        ItemList itemList = items.get(position);
        holder.companyname.setText(itemList.getCompanyName());
        holder.category.setText(itemList.getCategory());
        holder.idcomp.setText(itemList.getIdcomp());
        holder.udm.setText(itemList.getUdm());
        holder.name.setText(itemList.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public TextView companyname,category,idcomp,udm,name;
        List<ItemList> items=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
        Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View view, Context context,List<ItemList> items)
        {
            super(view);
            this.items=items;
            this.context=context;
            companyname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
            category=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.category);
            idcomp=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.idcomp);
            udm=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.udm);
            name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            cardlist=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.cardlist);
            replacecard=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.replacecard);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position=getAdapterPosition();
            ItemList itemList= this.items.get(position);
            cardlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            replacecard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }



////and XML File is



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/companyname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Copper Coil ac"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/category"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Category"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idcomp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ASN#001234"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center|start"

                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/udm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="UDM"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="narendar"

                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/replacecard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/listing_bg_active"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/companyname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Copper Coil ac"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/category"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Category"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idcomp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ASN#001234"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/remove"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/trash"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Remove"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/edit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/edit"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/detail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/view"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Detail"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>






</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the color of card-view.